# Parallel resolution of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have some promises to be resolved parallely. I can resolve them using Promise.all(). But what if these promises have promises inside them to be resolved too? Will they be automatically resolved or I have to manually resolve them before Promise.all() ?

Also, what method is preferred to resolve the promises? 
1. Collecting them and then using Promise.all()
2. creating promises and waiting for them to get resolved on their own?

Comment: "*I can resolve them using Promise.all()*" - no, `Promise.all` does not resolve anything, the promises need to do that on their own. `Promise.all` only creates a new promise that will wait for all the inputs.

Comment: I guess you are getting confused with the multithread environment. There is only a single-threaded event loop in js , so parallelism is tough unless you use, `process.fork()`

Comment: as long as you resolve the nested promises inside each promise all is good.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to resolve each promises within the parent separately to make sure that the Promise.all catches it just fine.

e.g,

```
const nestedAsyncChild = new Promise(resolve => resolve(someMethod));
const asyncChild = new Promise(resolve => resolve(nestedAsyncChild));

const parent1 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(asyncChild));
const parent2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(asyncChild));
const parent3 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(asyncChild));

Promise.all([parent1, parent2, parent3])
.then(a => {
  console.log("Success");
})
.catch(() => {
  console.error("Error");
});
```

### Update

If someone is down-voting an answer they should have the common courtesy to tell the person why that was being done. Chasing people off the answer-board does not help!